# What does "where" mean here and what is its role?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

Text:

> This comprehensive solution would constitute an integrated whole **where** nothing is agreed until everything is agreed. [Source](http://edition.cnn.com/2013/11/24/world/meast/iran-deal-text/index.html)

What does this where mean here? Does it mean "in which" or "while"? Looks like here where as a relative pronoun is used to refer to something which is not a place or situation. It is referring to the comprehensive solution.

Comment: Yes, it can be replaced with "in which".  It's a figurative use of "where".

Comment: (I think this is a duplicate of another question, but it's too difficult for me to find, I'm afraid.)

Comment: I answered it once. See this question: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/17183/the-meaning-of-where-in-your-secondary-mode-is-external-where-you-deal-with/17239#17239

Comment: And this comment in particular: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/17183/the-meaning-of-where-in-your-secondary-mode-is-external-where-you-deal-with/17239#comment31514_17239