# Can I use the relative pronoun "where" here?

Tags: relative-pronouns

In articles I have see extensively that the pronoun **where** is used to relate something which does not have anything to do with places, locations, sites, etc.. Consider:

> 1. Newton's second law of motion is given by ***F=ma*** where ***m*** is the mass, and ***a*** stands for the acceleration. ( concocted by me )
> 2. Furthermore, the incompatibility of timber growing and cattle grazing seems obvious where either of these two industries is to be conducted under intensive management. ( google book )
> 3. He grew up in a family where what he was supposed to be when he grew up was clear: he was to be an electrician ( google book )
> 4. Furthermore, the linear quadratic problem has been studied for systems where the evolution of the state is described by partial differential equations ( google book )

It seems that we can use **where** to describe a sentence, a procedure, a supposition and many things. Am I right? Would you provide me with more insights about this pronoun. With this regard, can I always describe something done by others, especially by researchers, using **where**?

---

*Additional Information*

***What is "describing something done by others,  especially by researchers"?***

Consider you are asked to conclude your research on a topic in the shape of research papers. So, at the beginning of the paper you start with introducing why it is important to research about that topic and review the previous works having similar topic. In this context, you summarize their work and discuss about their results to demonstrate why further investigation or studies is important. Thus, you need to describe sentences, procedures, suppositions, models, figures, assumptions, criteria, and others of that ilk. So, I want to know can I **always** use the pronoun **"where"** to describe/justify/paraphrase (relative clause) the previous works?

For example:

*They considered X where the authors neglect the Y.*

*X has been done where the marginal parameter Z was not taken into consideration.*

Comment: This reminds me of an old answer of mine: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/17183/the-meaning-of-where-in-your-secondary-mode-is-external-where-you-deal-with. Look for the usage note I found in The Free Dictionary: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/where.

Comment: @DamkerngT. I saw the links. Although I think they are relevant, my question narrowed down the usage of **where** in researches and scientific cases. The **usage tip** talks about mix feeling of the panel about prepositional usage.

Comment: There are several usage notes on that page. Look for the one taken from Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged, 12th Edition 2014 (the one I quoted in my comment under my answer to that question). Using *where* like this is not only limited to scientific contexts, BTW.

Comment: As a conjunction it has a broader sense than mere place. Check [this](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/where).

Comment: In contexts like *Divorce gets complicated where children are involved*, the metaphorically *spatial* pronoun ***where*** can be replaced by time-based ***when***, and in practice this usually doesn't affect the meaning at all (effectively, they both just mean ***if***).

Comment: Dictionaries show that "where" can refer to a situation, circumstance/set of circumstances, or a point in time as well as a location. So it seems answerable by simple reference to a dictionary. There is also a question whether it can "always be used to describe something done by others" which is so vague or general a question that it is unclear. With respect to the samples given, it's unclear why there would be a question pertaining to those if the definitions are understood. Why there would be a question particularly about *researchers* is also unclear. Voting to close as unclear.

Comment: @JimReynolds Is it really important why I want to write a scientific paper? Seriously? I cant understand you guys. If I ask a sentence construction question FumbleFingers votes for proofreading if I ask about sth general, one other guy votes for something else. Thank you for your suggestion, I know I can find answers in books and dictionaries. Ok, I will edit the question in order to make that more clear although I think it is clear enough.

Comment: I think that you probably understand the usage of the word well enough to use it pretty well, but maybe not enough to feel comfortable knowing exactly where (or when) you can use it or not. I don't think it's possible to answer yes or no to whether you can *always* use *where* to refer to *sentences, procedures, suppositions, models, figures, assumptions, criteria, and others of that ilk* or to *paraphrase previous work.*

Comment: Your question remains too general. I think I can understand your frustration. Have you tried to come into one of the chat rooms to ask about particular examples or see if someone will help you think about how to construct a question that will be accepted? It's not that people don't want to help you. There are "sentence" and pieces of language such that referring to them with *where* afterwards will be grammatical or ungrammatical and some where the meaning will be clear, nonsense, or in a gray area. I have a guess you still couldn't get a complete answer to the question as it stands.

Comment: *Researchers previously found the earth revolves around the sun where ___."* There is a sentence that I cannot imagine completing in a way that makes sense. So, then, is the answer to your question: No?

Comment: @JimReynolds Exactly. The problem is I always have doubt although I know something. I am obsessed with exceptions, connotation, .... . Perhaps since I am in a transition between an elementary learner to intermediate learner.

Comment: Oh. That would work. Yes. I think you now face a strategy question about how to form a clear rule for when it's permissible to use the word and not, and I think a comprehensive treatment of it would require a book to be written. Now that you've noticed it, you will attend to it in your future reading, and I think that's how you'll best learn about it. Meanwhile, be bold. I doubt you'll misuse it. There are ways of formulating questions if you want to submit particular examples that are less likely to be called proofreading: Explain what you think you understand, submit the example, and ask.

Comment: *Where* is certainly a relative word, but it's not a pronoun.  Only some relative words are relative pronouns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- *Where* often refers to a physical place, but it can also refer to something like *situation*.  Why is a situation considered a "place"?  Logically because a situation usually consists of some type of "area", explicit or assumed - within that area things are part of the situation and outside of that area things are not.
- Arranging or defining things tends to be considered to happen logically in a "space", which is described using location words.

> Newton's second law of motion is given by F=ma where m is the mass, and a stands for the acceleration.

The way I think about it, the word *where* here can be said to be "placing" or "arranging", in an abstract sense, definitions of *m* and *a* within or among the earlier phrase *F=ma*.

> Furthermore, the incompatibility of timber growing and cattle grazing seems obvious where either of these two industries is to be conducted under intensive management. ( google book )

In *situations where* these two industries are to be conducted under intensive management (we are drawing a line between these two industries + being conducted under intensive management versus anything else not fitting this criteria), the incompatibility of timber growing and cattle grazing seems obvious.

> He grew up in a family where what he was supposed to be when he grew up was clear: he was to be an electrician ( google book )

He is in a *situation where* he grew up in a family that  made clear what he was supposed to be when he grew up (we are drawing a line between belonging to his family and being outside of the family), and therefore he is to be an electrician.

Etc.

Answer (score 0):

The first example is in fact an innocent straightforward location-type where. The formula is somewhere in a book, on a blackboard, in your notes, on a screen, and it is *there* where you should think "energy" when you see the glyph E.

I have noticed the misunderstanding in various places. This probably arises because the formula is also (or even primarily) an abstract thing that expresses a fact or theory about our universe, an abstraction that is itself quite independent of the letters used. But an actual mathematician does not use letters at all when thinking of formulas: the abstraction is mentally represented directly, without the need for intervening glyphs. So the latter only make an appearance when the mathematician has to write the darn thing down - somewhere.